Plotly graph loading in PySide6
I am trying to render a plotly html file in pyside6, but I am getting a blank component where the plotly graph should be.  If I try to load the generated file in a web browser it works.
import os
import sys
import signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineSettings
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'region': ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California'],
    'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    'iso_code': ['US-AL', 'US-AK', 'US-AZ', 'US-AR', 'US-CA']
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create choropleth map
fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations='iso_code',   # Column with region codes (ISO codes)
    color='value',           # Column with values to map color intensity
    locationmode="USA-states", # Specify location mode (e.g., "USA-states" for US)
    scope="usa",             # Limit map scope
    color_continuous_scale="Blues"
)

# Save map to HTML
html_content = fig.to_html(full_html=True)

# Create a custom page class to catch console messages
class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        print(f"JS Console: {message} (Source: {sourceID}, Line: {lineNumber})")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up main tab widget
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        # Add choropleth map tab
        self.add_choropleth_tab()

    def add_choropleth_tab(self):
        # Create widget for the tab
        tab = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create QWebEngineView and load the HTML file
        web_view = QWebEngineView()

        # Enable JavaScript
        web_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        web_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
        web_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)

        html_file_path = os.path.abspath("choropleth_map.html")
        local_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(html_file_path)

        web_view.load(local_url)

        web_view.setPage(WebEnginePage())
        web_view.setHtml(html_content)
        layout.addWidget(web_view)

        tab.setLayout(layout)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(tab, "Choropleth Map")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())


Start by calling setAttribute() after calling setPage(); as the settings() docs explain, it's just a convenience function equivalent to view.page().settings(), meaning that setting attributes before setting a new page is completely pointless, since the new page will obviously not have those attributes set.
